# How to get multiple Consul KVs from different Consul context?

Tags: java, spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul, consul-kv

I have these KVs sources store on Consul:

```
config/books/<key>
config/common/<key>
```

And in my spring boot app application.yml, I have config it as following:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: sampleapp
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true
        prefix: config
        defaultContext: books
```

I know that this configuration that I made has pointed the app to read from ***config/books*** .

But I can't figure out how can I retrieve the Consul KV config from both ***config/common*** and ***config/books***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really flexible there, but it can be done if you rename your project and use defaultContext as well. Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/2.1.x/multi/multi_spring-cloud-consul-config.html) Spring Cloud Consul Config takes next paths:

```
config/testApp,dev/
config/testApp/
config/application,dev/
config/application/
```

where *testApp* - name of your app, *application* - default context

So with the following configuration it will work

```
spring:
  application:
    name: books
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true
        prefix: config
        defaultContext: common
```

Logs after running this configuration:

```
Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='consul', propertySources=[ConsulPropertySource {name='config/books/'}, ConsulPropertySource {name='config/common/'}]}
```